# SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty: "The data area passed to a system call is too small" error

Tags: c, windows, winapi, windows-xp, setupapi

I have a code that enumerates USB devices on Windows XP using SetupAPI:

```
    HDEVINFO hDevInfo = SetupDiGetClassDevs( &_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE, 0, 0, DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE | DIGCF_PRESENT);

    for (DWORD i = 0; ; ++i)
    {
        SP_DEVINFO_DATA devInfo;
        devInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVINFO_DATA);
        BOOL succ = SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(hDevInfo, i, &devInfo);
        if (GetLastError() == ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS)
            break;
        if (!succ) continue;

        DWORD devClassPropRequiredSize = 0;
        succ = SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(hDevInfo, &devInfo, SPDRP_COMPATIBLEIDS, NULL, NULL, 0, &devClassPropRequiredSize);
        if (!succ)
        {
           // This shouldn't happen!
           continue;
        }
    }
```

It used to work for years, but now I get `FALSE` from `SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty`, last error is "The data area passed to a system call is too small".
It seems that my call parameters correspond to the documentation for this function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551967(v=vs.85).aspx

Any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem was in your original code: `SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty` function may return `FALSE` (and set last error to `ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER`) when required property doesn't exist (or when its data is not valid, yes they have been lazy to pick a proper error code) so you should always check for `ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER` as a (not so) special case:

```
DWORD devClassPropRequiredSize = 0;
succ = SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(
    hDevInfo,
    &devInfo,
    SPDRP_COMPATIBLEIDS,
    NULL, 
    NULL, 
    0,
    &devClassPropRequiredSize);

if (!succ) {
    if (ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER == GetLastError() {
        // I may ignore this property or I may simply
        // go on, required size has been set in devClassPropRequiredSize
        // so next call should work as expected (or fail in a managed way).
    } else {
        continue; // Cannot read property size
    }
}
```

Usually you may simply ignore this error when you're reading property size (if `devClassPropRequiredSize` is still zero you can default it to proper constant for maximum allowed length). If property can't be read then next call `SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty` will fail (and you'll manage error there) but often you're able to read value and your code will work smoothly.